# How to convert form field data before saving to database in a Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm creating an "edit" page in Django python framework (template 'edit_page.html') where user should be able to edit existing data stored in a database. For now I can easily retrieve existing raw data in user form (a Django template), my issue is that I need to convert data populated by user before saving the form.

I have an 'ipv4' field in my model mapping a database table column with IPv4 addresses stored as unsigned int. For instance ip address '10.0.0.0' is stored as 167772160 in the database. 
Data conversion for 'ipv4' could be implemented as follows (exemple):

```
# Convert from raw database to human friendly format (167772160 -> 10.0.0.0)
import ipaddress
ipv4_raw = 167772160
ipv4_friendly = str(ipaddress.ip_address(ipv4_raw))
print(ipv4_friendly)
# Output: 10.0.0.0

# Convert from human friendly format to raw database format (10.0.0.0 -> 167772160 )
import ipaddress
ipv4_friendly = '10.0.0.0'
ipv4_raw = int(ipaddress.ip_address(ipv4_friendly))
print(ipv4_raw)
# Output: 167772160
```

My form needs to show human friendly 'ipv4' to the user but must have the capability to update the database column in 'raw' format (int).

'ipv4' must be converted from raw format to user friendly format for display and the other way around for database update.

Where should I perform this operation and how? So far I have the following implementation where IP is displayed in raw format.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Items(models.Model):
    ipv4 = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Items'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Items

MyEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ipv4'] = forms.CharField(label='IPv4',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))

    def clean_ip(self):
        import ipaddress
        ip = int(ipaddress.ip_address(self.cleaned_data['ipv4']))
        return ipv4

    class Meta(object):
        model = Items
        fields = ('ipv4')
```

**views.py**

```
def item_edit(request,item_id):

    item_id = int(item_id)
    item = Items.objects.get(id = item_id)

    redirect_url = 'https://domain.tld/items/' + str(item_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':  
        my_edit_form = MyEditForm(request.POST,instance=item)

        if my_edit_form.is_valid():
            my_edit_form.save()
            return redirect(redirect_url)
    else:
        my_edit_form = MyEditForm(instance=item)

    return render(request,'device_edit_form.html',{
        'item': item,
        'my_edit_form': my_edit_form
    })
```

**editpage.html**

```
{% block page_content %}
    <form id="my-edit-form" method="post" action="" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ my_edit_form.ipv4.label_tag }}
            {{ my_edit_form.ipv4 }}
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom field, something like:

```
import ipaddress

class MyIPField(forms.CharField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if value:
            return str(ipaddress.ip_address(value))
        return value

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            ip = int(ipaddress.ip_address(value))
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError('Not valid IP address')

        return ip
```

And reference it in the form `__init__`:

```
self.fields['ipv4'] = MyIPField(label='IPv4', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

In this case you don't need `clean_ip` method.

Another solution would be to have two model fields (for raw and friendly ip) and save the raw value manually after form validation goes well.

Comment: Thanks, this work well when 'ipv4' when field has a valid IP, but it throws an error when data entered is not in the expected type which prevents rendering of template page. Why in this case error is not handled by the form error field mechanism (eg. ipv4.errors)? How can I display the error in the UI like: <p>{{ my_edit_form.ipv4.name }} : {{ ipv4.errors }}</p> for instance instead?